# Public Property as ObjectDataSource Select Parameter

Tags: asp.net-4.0, objectdatasource

I have an ODS, which is bound to an ADO.NET datatable. There is one select parameter. I would like to use a public property which I have declared in my code-behind as the select parameter, something like:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID='<%# EInfoProperty %>' Name="quote_header_id" 
        PropertyName="headerId" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

The above syntax doesn't work, and I've been unable to find anything here, on MSDN or on Google that might help here. Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck sticking the value in the Session, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything I could find, this is not currently possible. For my purposes, I ended up putting the value in question in the session and using a SessionParameter.